# Why doesn't the bromide anion attack during electrophilic addition of bromine in methanol solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, halides, hydrocarbons, c-c-addition

It is known that addition of bromine (in methanol) to ethene will yield 1-bromo-2-methoxyethane. The reaction proceeds with the formation of a bromonium intermediate in the first step. In the second step, methanol attacks either carbon through the lone pair on its oxygen atom. In the last step, the $\ce{CH3OH+}$ loses a proton, which combines with the bromide anion obtained in the first step, to release $\ce{HBr}$ as a by-product.

**My question:** Why doesn't the $\ce{Br-}$ (obtained in the first step) attack as a nucleophile in the second step?

We know that nucleophilicity is directly proportional to the atom's charge and size. Bromide anion has a unit negative charge as opposed to the neutral oxygen atom in methanol. Bromide anion is also much larger in size. Both these factors favor bromide anion being a much better nucleophile than the neutral oxygen atom in methanol. Yet, the latter only attacks in the second step. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very simple explanation for this. Your reasoning regarding $\ce{Br-}$ being a better nucleophile is absolutely correct. The reason as to why methanol attacks instead of $\ce{Br-}$ is because it is the $\mathsf{\color{red}{solvent}}$. The solvent concentration is simply too high. Only one $\ce{Br-}$ is generated.

More or less the answer is this paragraph from J. Clayden - section "Unsymmetrical bromonium ions open regioselectively" in chapter 20 "Electrophilic addition to alkenes" :

> ...when a bromination is done in a nucleophilic solvent—water or methanol, for example—solvent molecules compete with the bromide to open the bromonium ion. As
>   you know, alcohols are much worse nucleophiles than bromide but, **because the concentration of solvent is so high** (remember—the concentration of water in water is $\pu{55M}$), **the solvent gets there first most of the time.** This is what happens when isobutene is treated with bromine in methanol. An ether is formed by attack of methanol only at the more substituted end of the bromonium ion.
>
> [image]

---

**Note**: Concentration of pure methanol is around $\pu{24.75 M}$, calculated from the density given on [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.864.html)